# Can a single component installed by two different installers, if we keep same GUIDs and Paths for files,services, registries, upgrade codes?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Can a product installed by two different installers, if we keep same GUIDs and Paths for files,services, registries, upgrade codes? Install by installer1 and uninstalled by other installer2, or upgraded by installer2

I have a component, is bundled with two installers 
One is bundled as MSM module in Installer with multiple other components.

And other I have standalone installer that installs my component, it does not have MSM module just has .wixproj and .wxs file.

So my question is can I have compatibility in between standalone installer and Bundled installer
(component installed by Standalone can upgraded by Bundled component installer and vice versa)

I know this can be done using shared MSM but trying to acomplomplish it with minimum changes just USE same **GUIDs** and **PATHs**.

Also how uninstallation will work, if uninstalled by Bundled installer, what will happen if uninstall triggered by 
clicking  "remove" standalone installer. also vice versa case "uninstalled by standalone installer and then tried to uninstall bundled uninstallation"

Please consider I have used common Filepaths and GUIDs for components. Is this sufficient? Consuming existing standalone installer.

I feel consuming same MSM in standalone installer may be longer path.

wanted to know is this possible? if yes what additional steps I have to perform.

Comment: Please try to improve this question - it is somewhat unclear what you are doing. It seems you are already aware that you should use merge modules for shared components.

Comment: Thanks Updated question

Comment: I've never found merge modules to be useful in satisfying needs that I've had. But, I believe they are "erased" upon being merged; meaning the resulting database is no different whether a merge module was used or not.

Comment: This question is still very confusing. I guess WiX is some extraneous contextual information but WiX has "bundles" outside the context of Windows Installer so that also makes it hard to read.