# Application that is to be installed by two different MSI installers

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a **Application** that is to be installed by two different MSI installers, **INSTALLER1** and **INSTALLER2**.
So can this achieved by keeping same **GUID** and **PATHs**.
Use case 1. APPLICATION installed by **INSTALLER1** and after some time uninstalled by **INSTALLER2**, will it notify to INSTALLER1 that it has been uninstalled?
         2. APPLICATION installed by **INSTALLER1** and after some time upgraded by **INSTALLER2**, will it notify to INSTALLER1?
Or do need to check other things such as Upgrade code, package code, Component ID should be same( in addition to GUID)

Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: I have a question. You use the term 'installer' here, but somehow you distinguish 'installer' from your Windows Installer (MSI) package. Can you clarify your question a bit? I don't know what you mean by 'PRODUCT'. Is the 'PRODUCT' a component within a single MSI installer? Are you bundling your MSI installer in a wrapper like InstallShield Suite that will install your MSI?

Answer (score 0):

I found another post, that I think is your post as well.
[Can a single component installed by two different installers, if we keep same GUIDs and Paths for files,services, registries, upgrade codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215788/can-a-single-component-installed-by-two-different-installers-if-we-keep-same-gu)

You are using the term 'product' in a confusing manner. 
In your other post you reference merge modules, these are a collection of files arranged in components. Your merge module will be consumed by another installation package. There is NO upgrade code for a merge module, there is no package code, or product code either.

If I am understanding your question, if you have configured your components correctly in the merge module, then the component rules will take effect no matter how many products install your application. There is no 'notification' needed.

So, let's say you create your merge module, and the files install to C:\Program Files\MyGreatApp. 
MSI_1 and MSI_2 consume your Merge Module 1.0.0. 
A customer installs MSI_2, at this time your component information is written to the registry and indicates that MyGreatApp component is version 1.0.0
Later the customer installs MSI_1, at this time when it installs, it notices that MyGreatApp component is already installed and is version 1.0.0, the component will not install at this time because it already exists on the system.
Let's say you release MyGreatApp v2.0.0 and MSI_2 consumes this merge module. 
If a customer installs MSI_1, then MyGreatApp v1.0.0 is installed
If a customer later installs MSI_2, the install sees that the component is installed, but the version is 1.0.0, so based on component rules, it has a newer version.

So, from an installer issue, this should honor component rules.

The question you have to ask is that when your app is upgraded from v1.0.0 to v2.0.0, will that cause a break in the code. If your files are compiled separately from the main MSI you should be all set, however, if your files are used as references in the primary application, and this is a .NET assembly that uses strong name key file, you will get dependency not found errors.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when configuring your components in the merge module, you must make sure they are flagged for shared. That way the target system will keep count of how many times the component(s) have been installed and the files will remain until the component count is zero.

Comment: Thanks for helpfull answer, Just wanted to know it upgrades successfully but Why it is failing to uninstall my application when it has same GUID, PATH, with flag "shared ".